# Get google calendar event ID in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es

I am trying to delete an event from google calendar in node.js, 
and this requires an ID for the event to be deleted.

I didn't find any way to get this Id in the google calendar documentation.
Is there a way to get the event Id using a specific method?

```
function deleteEvent(agent) {
console.log('delete event function');


    //Check the availability of the time slot and set up an appointment if the time slot is available on the calendar
    return getEventId().then(() => {
      agent.add(`Got it. the event deleted`);
    }).catch(() => {
      agent.add(`Sorry`);
    });

  }
  function getEventId(){


  console.log("get event id function");

  eventId='******';
  return deleteCalendarEvent().then(()=>{
    console.log('success');
  }).catch(()=>{
    console.log('fail');
  });



  }// getEmailsForDepartment

  function deleteCalendarEvent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      calendar.events.delete({  
        auth: serviceAccountAuth,
        calendarId: calendarId,

        eventId:eventId
      }, (err, event) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: could you show me your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate how you expect to know or figure out what Event to delete in the first place.

But, for example, if the request is to "delete the 5pm event", you can use a Dialogflow `@sys.time` Entity Type to get the date and time, and then use the Calendar API's [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method, specifying the `timeMin` and possibly `timeMax` parameters to find events that match.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Events: list` to list all events. Then filter by title, date, or similar to get the id of the event you want. See  https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

In the browser UI, you see the eid if you click on Troubleshooting info.